# Why can't my browser resolve a hostname through /etc/hosts?

Tags: dns, bind

I set up a Apache2 on a new Solaris machine on my company's internal (firewalled) network and configured it for [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).

We don't yet have a domain for the new machine, so I created my own, "lsiden.net", and named the host something like "myhost.lsiden.net" in the httpd.conf <VirtualHost> directive.

Since no such domain is registered, I created the entry "w.x.y.z  myhost.lsiden.net" in my /etc/hosts file.  (I will delete it when we get a real domain name.)

I can ping myhost.lsiden.net but if I type it in either IE7 or Google Chrome 10, it won't resolve.  Is there something that is preventing each browser from looking in the /etc/hosts file?

(In order to access my company's VPN, I have to use the machine that they configured for me which was provisioned with Windows XP.  So /etc/hosts is actually something like c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, but that shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Check your /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/resolv.conf. Both control how DNS resolution works on the local machine.

Comment: You use IE/Chrome on the Solaris?

Comment: No. A Solaris machine hosts the site.  I must use IE or Chrome (or FF) on a Win-XP computer to access the site because of VPN and company IT restrictions.

Comment: On Windows, there is no nsswitch.conf or resolv.conf.  Is there some equivalent that controls whether or not DNS will look first in .../etc/hosts?

Comment: I found [this post](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2004/10/tweak-your-windows-hosts-file.html) that suggested that I restart the DNS cache on Windows.  Tried it.  Can ping it with my URI, but still can't reach it from the browser.  Rats!@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as 'why does one work and not the other' one thing to remember is that ping uses a different protocol (icmp) than http (tcp). Can you check firewalls on your Windows host? A lot of VPNs are configured to firewall certain things.

The next step after ping is the old webmaster (I'm dating myself by using that term) tool: telnet.

Can you try:

```
telnet <machine> <port>
```

from your Windows box.

If this doesn't connect, you have connection issues.  Possibly a firewall, or something else.

If it does connect, try typing:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: <nameOfVirtualHost>
```

<kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>

Which then should show you your page.

I'd flush the system DNS cache if you haven't yet:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Browsers themselves may use a DNS cache.  I know Chrome does, couldn't find a way to flush it.  There's a Firefox [plugin that flushes DNS cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dns-cache/)

Comment: First, I had to reboot Windows ;).  Then I tried your telnet suggestion.  I didn't get back a page but I got this in the access log:  "10.195.51.65 - - [25/Mar/2011:12:25:42 -0400] "GET GET\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bGET / HTTP/1.0" 400 226".  The backspaces are a consequence of my term (Putty) not echoing anything to me in telnet so I can't see WTF I'm doing!  But something is definitely working now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Expanding on M'vy's comment)

**It is the *client* which performs the name resolution.**

On windows this can be done through the [hosts file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx#EDAA) (link includes all resolution methods).

Happy ... networking.

Comment: I already said I put entries in /etc/hosts.  That's what this question is about.

Comment: @Isiden you mentioned /etc/hosts, which makes it sound like a UNIX machine you were editing on, and later mentioned it was the Windows equivalent. That's what @pst was responding to.